# how to disable push notifications by condition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application, I want to send notifications only to authorized users,
authorization occurs by token if the token is empty, then the user is not authorized, for authorization and storing the token I use the shared_pref package. How can I disable notifications if the user is not logged in?
Token validation is only done in MyAppState notifications I need to disable in the same place

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await Permission.notification.request();

  if(Constants.USER_TOKEN.isEmpty) {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.setAutoInitEnabled(false);
  }
  RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  if (initialMessage != null) {
    if (navKey.currentState != null) {
      if(Constants.USER_TOKEN.isNotEmpty) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NotificationScreen()));
      }
      print('Message');
    }
  }
  await _messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? android = message.notification!.android;
    if (notification != null && android != null) {
      flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        notification.hashCode,
        notification.title,
        notification.body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id,
            channel.name,
            channelDescription: channel.description,
            icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage? message) {
    print("On message opened app: ${message?.data}}");
    if (navKey.currentState != null) {
      if(Constants.USER_TOKEN.isNotEmpty) {
        navKey.currentState!.push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => const NotificationScreen()));
      }
    }
  });

  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
      const AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_notification');

  var initializationSettingsIOS = const DarwinInitializationSettings();

  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
  await _messaging.requestPermission();
  String? token = await _messaging.getToken();
  if (token != null) {
    print("FIREBASE TOKEN $token");
  } else {
    print("CANNOT TAKE FIREBASE TOKEN");
  }
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    var APNS = await _messaging.getAPNSToken();
    print('APNS: $APNS');
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      Constants.USER_TOKEN = pref.getString('login') ?? "";
    });
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() async {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    await getToken();
  }
```

Comment: By token do you mean by firebase token? There is another way you can go about on this, when a user logs into your app, just subscribe to a firebase topic and when they log out you can unsubscribe from that topic. Sending notification through topics is the right way to do. For different actions taken by users, you can subscribe to different topics. Let's say if a user visits your store page but never purchases, you can subscribe them to a specific topic and send notification to people only subscribed to that topic.

Comment: I mean my Constants.USER_TOKEN, not firebase

Comment: if you are not using firebase tokens, just use topics then. This way you will know which customers are receiving your notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [deleteToken](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/deleteToken.html) which invalidates the current token and [getToken](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/getToken.html) again to get a new one when enabling.

```
getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();


    setState(() {
      Constants.USER_TOKEN = pref.getString('login') ?? "";
    });

if(Constants.USER_TOKEN.isEmpty()){

    // delete firebase token

}else{

    // get firebase token

}
     }
```